# Pagination problem with Django haystack

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-haystack, django-pagination

i'm using django-haystack with simple engine, the search is fine, but the pagination is not working. This is the code of my search results template

```
{% if query %}
<br>
<div id="contenido_pagina">                
    {% for result in page.object_list %}
    {% if result.object.get_model == '[Video] ' %}
    {% if result.object.publicar %}
    <div class="salida_search">
        <a href="{{result.object.get_full_url}}">{{result.object.get_model}}{{result.object.nombre}}</a><br>
        <div class="resumen_search">
            {{result.object.sinopsis|safe|truncatewords:"30"}}
        </div>
        <div class="link_search">
            <a href="{{result.object.get_full_url}}">{{result.object.anio}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% else %}
    <div class="salida_search">
        <a href="{{result.object.get_full_url}}">{{result.object.get_model}}{{result.object.titulo}}</a><br>
        <div class="resumen_search">
            {% if result.object.contenido %}
            {{result.object.contenido|safe|truncatewords:"30"}}
            {% else %}
            {{result.object.sinopsis|safe|truncatewords:"30"}}
            {% endif %}
        </div>
        <div class="link_search">
            <a href="{{result.object.get_full_url}}">{{result.object.fecha|date:"d M Y"}}</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    {% empty %}
    <div>La busqueda <span class="highlighted">{{query}}</span> no obtuvo ningun resultado</div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if page.has_previous or page.has_next %}
    <div>
        {% if page.has_previous %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">{% endif %}&laquo; Anterior{% if page.has_previous %}</a>{% endif %}
        |
        {% if page.has_next %}<a href="?q={{ query }}&amp;page={{ page.next_page_number }}">{% endif %}Siguiente &raquo;{% if page.has_next %}</a>{% endif %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
</div>    
<br>
{% else %}
{# Show some example queries to run, maybe query syntax, something else? #}
{% endif %}
```

when i go to the next page i see the same objects that first page. What i am doing wrong??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue as well. From debugging the code it looks like it's an issue with the paginator and the searchqueryset. Unfortunately i didn't have more time to devote to it and ended up moving on to whoosh for development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered this.  Seems as though it's a known limitation of the simple backend.

https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/320